# Access page based on level

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `userdatabase` which contains "`Approver 1`" and "`Approver 2`" with bit(1,0) datatype.

```
[Approver 1]       BIT          DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
[Approver 2]       BIT          DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
```

I would like to allow only either approver 1 or approver 2 to access certain page, such as `Approval.aspx` where other user will be redirect to `main.aspx`.

How can i do it?

I saw something like this, but don't know what to put for `<allow>` and `<deny>`.

```
<location path="Approval.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny ???/>
      <allow ??? />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you seen this http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
<location path="Approval.aspx"  >
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="*"/> 
    <allow roles="Approver1"/>            
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Putting `*` in deny will deny other anonymous users from accessing above page.If you wish to allow everyone to certain page then you could use

```
<allow users="*"/>
```

### Alternatively you can do

> `if (User.IsInRole("rolename")) {
>     // my action redirect
>   }`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. May i know how to set the roles as `Approval1`?  and i believe allow shall come before deny...

Comment: Is there any role defined like Approver1 in your system?

Comment: I only have a `Approver1` column in database table to set `true` or `false`.